# How do I make or get computer certificates to use with IPSEC user authentication on Windows?

Tags: authentication, windows, certificates, ipsec

I am having trouble and need some direction using computer certificates with Windows 7 firewall IP Security rules, using certificates only for user authentication. I can get everything to work correctly using a passphrase for user authentication. However, I would like to use certificates.

I cannot find any documentation on the requirements to make certificates for IPSEC user authentication.

I have been using `makecert` to create the third party CA then made some certificates using the following ekus:

```
Server Authentication EKU is        1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
IP security IKE intermediate EKU is 1.3.6.1.5.5.8.2.2
Client Certificate EKU is           1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2
```

Does anyone know of a good resource or documentation for Windows 7 firewall that includes this message? Or has anyone created these kind of certificates before and would be willing to assist me?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of making the certificates and requiring the server to use certificate authentication, have a look at this resource: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814394

In order to get the certificates, the following is a handy way to do it over HTTPS so you won't need to get into reconfiguring firewall rulesets to permit: 
https://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/02/01/certificate-enrollment-web-services.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: The question is about IPsec, not TLS.

Answer (score 1):

I have just established an IPSEC site-to-site VPN that required some ExtendedKeyUsage and I did some research on it.

The ExtendedKeyUsage for Internet Key Exchange were deprecated by [RFC4945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4945)

> The CA SHOULD NOT include the ExtendedKeyUsage (EKU) extension in    certificates for use with IKE.  Note that there were three IPsec-
> related object identifiers in EKU that were assigned in 1999.  The
> semantics of these values were never clearly defined.  The use of
> these three EKU values in IKE/IPsec is obsolete and explicitly
> deprecated by this specification.  CAs SHOULD NOT issue certificates
> for use in IKE with them.  (For historical reference only, those
> values were id-kp-ipsecEndSystem, id-kp-ipsecTunnel, and id-kp-
> ipsecUser.)

If this certificate will be used only for IKE/IPSEC, the recommendation is to set the KeyUsage to digitalSignature, nonRepudiation or both.

> IKE uses an end-entity certificate in the authentication process.
> The end-entity certificate may be used for multiple applications.  As
> such, the CA can impose some constraints on the manner that a public
> key ought to be used.  The KeyUsage (KU) and ExtendedKeyUsage (EKU)
> extensions apply in this situation.
>
> Since we are talking about using the public key to validate a
> signature, if the KeyUsage extension is present, then at least one of
> the digitalSignature or the nonRepudiation bits in the KeyUsage
> extension MUST be set (both can be set as well).  It is also fine if
> other KeyUsage bits are set.
>
> A summary of the logic flow for peer cert validation follows:
>
> o  If no KU extension, continue.
>
> o  If KU present and doesn't mention digitalSignature or
> nonRepudiation (both, in addition to other KUs, is also fine),
> reject cert.
>
> o  If none of the above, continue.